# Change address of struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Let's say that I was given a struct and I need to assign all of it's attributes to a particular address. The code below is giving me a conditional error, but i'm not trying to evaluate it.

```
struct header block_o_data;
block_o_data.a = 1;
block_o_data.b = 2;
void* startingAddress = sbrk(0);
&block_o_data = *address;
```

Please let me know what im doing wrong.

Comment: You never change the address of an object in C during its entire life-time. The address is an object's identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a struct like this:

```
struct mystruct {
    int a;
    char b;
};
```

then you probably need something like this:

```
// A pointer variable supposed to point to an instance of the struct
struct mystruct *pointer;

// This is a general address represented by void*
void *addr = some_function(0);

// Cast that general address to a pointer varibale pointing to
// an instance of the struct
pointer = (struct mystruct *) addr;

// Use it!
printf("%d", pointer->a);
```

Comment: what does the "->" operator mean?

Comment: so would this be valid: "pointer->a = 1"
in terms of assigning data to pointer?

Answer (score 3):

In the assignment to `block_o_data`, you're taking its address and trying to assign a value to it.  The address of a variable is not an **lvalue**, meaning the expression cannot appear on the left side of an assignment.

You need to declare a *pointer* to a struct, then assign it the address of where the values actually live:

```
struct header *block_o_data;
void* startingAddress = sbrk(0);
block_o_data = startingAddress;
```

Comment: Does this still work if I assign values to block_o_data before I try to set an address to it?