# ATSAME51 CAN works with no compiler optimizations, error with optimizations

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, compiler-optimization, can-bus

I've written a CAN driver for an ATSAME51 on a Microchip IGAT dev board and when I compile with no optimizations the program runs fine and is able to transmit and receive data. When I turn on any amount of compiler optimizations it doesn't work and throws all the error flags and turns the bus off (Error Passive, Error Warning, and Bus Off bits all set). The Last Error Code (LEC) in the Protocol Status (PSR) register is 0x2 (Form Error: A fixed format part of a received frame has the wrong format).

I've gone through and looked at all the registers with and without optimizations in case something wasn't getting written and they're all the same. All the CAN registers, all the GCLK registers for clocking the CAN peripheral, and the IO registers for multiplexing. The only thing that is different is the address of the FIFOs which is still in a valid location (in the first 64 KB area of the system RAM) and I've stepped through each line of can_tx_immediate to make sure the data actually gets correctly put into the FIFO and it does.

I'm really hoping there's an obvious error someone can point out to me because this is driving me clinically insane!

## **main.c**

```
#include "sam.h"
#include "drivers/drivers.h"

int main(void)
{
    system_config_all_clk();
    
    io_set_pin_mux(PORTB, PORT_PB12, SET_PIN_MUX_H);
    io_set_pin_mux(PORTB, PORT_PB13, SET_PIN_MUX_H);
    can_init(CAN1);
    
    /* Replace with your application code */
    while (1) 
    {
        can_test();
    }
}
```

## **canbus.c**

```
#define CAN_TX_FIFO_SIZE        2
#define CONF_CAN1_BTP_TSEG2     2
#define CONF_CAN1_BTP_TSEG1     13
#define CONF_CAN1_BTP_BRP       1
#define CONF_CAN1_BTP_SJW       1


volatile static uint8_t can1_rx_fifo[CAN1_RX_FIFO_ELEMENTS * 16] __attribute__((__aligned__(4)));
volatile static uint8_t can1_tx_fifo[CAN1_RX_FIFO_ELEMENTS * 16] __attribute__((__aligned__(4)));

void can_init(Can* canbus)
{
        /*Unlocks CAN1 for editing.*/
    canbus->CCCR.bit.INIT = 1;
    while (canbus->CCCR.bit.INIT != 1) {}
    canbus->CCCR.bit.CCE = 1;
    
    /*Defines memory priority for message RAM access as not sensitive operation (lowest priority).*/
    canbus->MRCFG.reg = CAN_MRCFG_QOS_DISABLE;
    
    /*Sets up the time quanta timing for normal speed operation (1Mbps).*/
    canbus->NBTP.reg = CAN_NBTP_NBRP(CONF_CAN1_BTP_BRP - 1) | CAN_NBTP_NTSEG1(CONF_CAN1_BTP_TSEG1 - 1)                                    
                    | CAN_NBTP_NTSEG2(CONF_CAN1_BTP_TSEG2 - 1) | CAN_NBTP_NSJW(CONF_CAN1_BTP_SJW - 1);
                    
    /*RX FIFO 0 configuration, blocking mode, watermark interrupt disabled, sets buffer size and start address.*/
    canbus->RXF0C.reg = CAN_RXF0C_F0S(CAN1_RX_FIFO_ELEMENTS) | CAN_RXF0C_F0SA((uint32_t)can1_rx_fifo);
    
    /*Sets the size of data field for the RX/TX FIFO, operating in CAN2.0B not FD, so this is always 8 bytes.*/
    canbus->RXESC.reg = CAN_RXESC_F0DS_DATA8;
    canbus->TXESC.reg = CAN_TXESC_TBDS_DATA8;
    
    /*Sets the size and start address of the TX FIFO.*/
    canbus->TXBC.reg = CAN_TXBC_TFQS(CAN1_TX_FIFO_ELEMENTS) | CAN_TXBC_TBSA((uint32_t)can1_tx_fifo);
    
    /*Reset the CCE and INIT bits to start CAN operation.*/
    canbus->CCCR.bit.CCE = 0;
    canbus->CCCR.bit.INIT = 0;
    while (canbus->CCCR.bit.INIT != 0) {}   
}

int32_t can_tx_immediate(Can* canbus, can_tx_fifo_entry_t* message)
{
    volatile can_tx_fifo_entry_t* f = NULL;
    uint32_t put_index;

    /*Check if FIFO is full.*/
    if (canbus->TXFQS.bit.TFQF != 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    /*Determine which index to put the new msg at.*/
    put_index = canbus->TXFQS.bit.TFQPI;

    if (canbus == CAN1) {
        /*Set the address of f based on the put index.*/
        f = (can_tx_fifo_entry_t*)(can1_tx_fifo + put_index * 16);
    }

    if (f == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    /*Copy into FIFO.*/
    memcpy(f, message, 16);

    /*Request the transmission.*/
    canbus->TXBAR.reg = 1 << put_index;
}

void can_test()
{
    volatile can_tx_fifo_entry_t new_msg;
    
    /*Initialize these to zero.*/
    new_msg.T0.val = 0;
    new_msg.T1.val = 0;
    
    new_msg.data[0] = 0x00;
    new_msg.data[1] = 0x01;
    new_msg.data[2] = 0x02;
    new_msg.data[3] = 0x03;
    new_msg.T0.bit.ESI = 0;
    new_msg.T0.bit.XTD = 0;             //Standard length ID.
    new_msg.T0.bit.RTR = 0;             //Standard frame.
    new_msg.T0.bit.ID  = 0x69 << 18;    //Standard length ID needs to be passed down 18 bits.
    new_msg.T1.bit.DLC = 4;             //4 bytes of data.
    new_msg.T1.bit.FDF = 0;             //Not FD mode.
    new_msg.T1.bit.BRS = 0;             //No bit rate switching.
    new_msg.T1.bit.EFC = 0;             //Dont store events.
    can_tx_immediate(CAN1, &new_msg);   
}
```

Here is the CANbus running with no compiler optimizations.
[image: CAN bus running with no compiler optimizations]

And here is with optimizations. It does this once before shutting it self off with "Bus Off" mode. After this happens the Error Passive, Error Warning, and Bus Off bits are set and the Last Error Code (LEC) in the Protocol Status (PSR) register is 0x2 (Form Error: A fixed format part of a received frame has the wrong format.)
[image: CANbus running with compiler optimizations.]

Comment: Without looking at the code, almost always these symptoms mean your code has undefined behaviour.  Build with clang or gcc `-Wall -fsanitize=undefined -O1` if that's possible (it might not be since the UBsan libraries probably aren't available for an embedded target.  But if you can mock up anything with dummy `volatile` variables to run the same code on your host desktop, that would be a good idea.)  In this case it's also possible that speed / timing is an issue, if unoptimized builds waited longer between two I/Os.

Comment: What's the point of `volatile` on `can_tx_fifo_entry_t new_msg;`?  That's a local variable.  The thing that needs to be `volatile` is the assignment to the actual FIFO, like `*f = new_msg;` (which should work since `f` is a pointer-to-volatile).  But instead you used `memcpy(f, message, 16);` which takes a plain non-`volatile` pointer; the compiler could be doing dead-store elimination when you loop on `can_test`.  GCC and clang should warn about discarding volatile: https://godbolt.org/z/MehqcheG6

Comment: Also, generally use `sizeof(something)` instead of hardcoding 16 as a memcpy ize.  Use `_Static_assert` if you need to check that your struct size matches what the I/O device is expecting.  Or if your struct has bookkeeping members that don't get copied to the FIFO, then maybe hardcode the 16 in memcpy but also `static_assert` on an `offsetof(struct foo, member)` or something.

Comment: @PeterCordes That volatile was there for no good reason, I was getting frustrated and starting adding them anywhere hoping something would work without understanding what I was doing. I got rid of the volatile and memcpy and unfortunately it didn't fix the issue, but at least the code is better written now.

Comment: @PeterCordes The ATSAM CAN controller parts use DMA to transfer results directly into RAM. So these are to be regarded as DMA buffers and they should absolutely be `volatile`.

Comment: @AlexJegers See comment above. Furthermore, on some parts with lots of RAM you need to ensure that the CAN buffers are placed in the lower part of the RAM. But you already know that, yeah? I recall this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77755963/584518

Comment: For 1MHz you should probably increase synchronization jump width to 2 or 3, particularly if running on the internal oscillator which is good, but still dubious to use for baudrates that high. Generally you should use external quartz for baudrates >= 250kbps.

Comment: From what I recall (and I may be wrong here), you should still set up the `DBTP` register even when not using CANFD. To the very same values as used for `NBTP`.

Comment: `can1_rx_fifo[CAN1_RX_FIFO_ELEMENTS * 16]` is fishy. What's `CAN1_RX_FIFO_ELEMENTS`, 16 as well? Why do you pick a size 16*16? Or if it isn't 16 but 1 or something, then `CAN_RXF0C_F0S` is setup all wrong. Could be a bug. Also later you use the magic number 16 `memcpy(f, message, 16);`.

Comment: `can1_tx_fifo` is declared using a size determined by `CAN1_RX_FIFO_ELEMENTS` should that not `CAN1_TX_FIFO_ELEMENTS`?

Comment: `CAN_TX_FIFO_SIZE` is defined but not used, while `CAN1_TX_FIFO_ELEMENTS` is used, but there is no definition in the provided code.

Comment: @Clifford Yeah, thank you for those catches... I cleaned it up. `CAN1_RX_FIFO_ELEMENTS` and `CAN1_TX_FIFO_ELEMENTS` are the same size anyways so it wasn't effecting anything now but likely saved me another headache down the line.

Comment: @Lundin `can1_rx_fifo[CAN1_RX_FIFO_ELEMENTS * 16]` is how Microchip did it in the ASF library so I copied it. The 16 is because 1 FIFO element is 16 bytes and it's an array of uint8_t. I've now changed this to be an array of type can_rx_fifo_t - `volatile static can_rx_fifo_t can1_rx_fifo[CAN1_RX_FIFO_ELEMENTS]` where `CAN1_RX_FIFO_ELEMENTS` is the size of the fifo. I feel like this is more readable and eliminates the magic number.

Comment: @Lundin Given that it operates fine with no compiler optimization I didn't expect it to be a timing issue from a hardware perspective. Regardless, I changed the sync jump width to 2 and also decreased the baud to 500kbps for the sake of testing.

Comment: @Lundin: I'm sure `volatile` is necessary somewhere, but not on the `volatile can_tx_fifo_entry_t new_msg;` local var in automatic storage whose only use is assignments to members, and then passing its address as a non-`volatile` function arg to `can_tx_immediate` which passes it to `memcpy`.  (Even if `can_tx_immediate` took a `volatile*`, `memcpy` would discard it.)

Comment: @AlexJegers I was rather thinking it could be a memory issue if you had not set the buffer sizes correctly or different in relation to what you told `RXF0C.reg`. Then the DMA may overwrite other variables out of bounds and a bug like that might expose itself in a release build, when variables are stored differently in memory.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hmm yeah only the actual buffers need to be `volatile`, though so does anything accessing them as well. Which won't work with memcpy. I'd probably roll out a hand-written memcpy just to not discard volatile qualifiers and risk some optimization goof-up, since strictly speaking "casting away" volatile leads to UB.

Comment: @Lundin: Not just "strictly speaking".  I'd fully expect GCC to do dead-store elimination on `memcpy(volatile_ptr, &tmp, 4);`, and in fact that is what happens: https://godbolt.org/z/3c5Wea6cd  . `memcpy` is acting just like `*(aliasing_unaligned_int*)ptr = tmp;` for a non-volatile type.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well that example isn't just UB, it is invalid C (constraint violation). But it is allowed language-wise to cast a qualified pointer to a non-qualified, but de-referencing leads to UB. Modding your example to use an external linkage `char*` makes gcc fall in line for some reason. https://godbolt.org/z/fYeb8Pjdf.

Comment: @Lundin: That "works" only because `memcpy` can alias anything, so each of the stores might have modified the global `char *p2`, since the 4 bytes pointed-to by `volatile char *p` might overlap its static storage.  Notice that the code-gen reloads `p2` each time, as well as doing the stores.